# How can I get CMake to _not_ create a DartConfiguation.tcl file?

Tags: build, dart, cmake

I'm writing this CMake project with a tests folder. Now, whenever run `make` in my build folder, a `DartConfiguration.tcl` gets created. I don't think I really need it... why would it be created? And can I arrange it so that it isn't?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are including the `CTest` module.  Try using [`enable_testing()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/enable_testing.html) instead.  The `CTest` module is for `Configure a project for testing with CTest/CDash` which then runs the steps for creating the `DartConfiguration.tcl`.  You can check it out yourself in `Modules\CTest.cmake`.

Comment: Well, it was suggested to me to include this module so as to have `BUILD_TESTING` config option. I suppose I could create it on my own.